# URL validation Without protocol

Tags: java, url

I Have used URLValidator class in java to validate URL . But I Want that if user won't give any protocol in URL then also the validation should be returned as valid.

Explaned Correctly: If this is supplied in URL "http://www.google.com" then also it should be a valid URL and if "www.google.com" is supplied then also the validation should returned as valid URL.

I have tried a lot .Please Help me in this.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I want URL validation that treats http://www.google.com and www.google.com both as correct URL. Presently I am using URLValidator class in java but it returns www.google.com as invalid URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check if that works for you:

```
boolean foundMatch = false;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:(https?|ftp|file)://|www\\.)?[-A-Z0-9+&#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]\\.[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    foundMatch = regexMatcher.matches();
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to prepend http (because that is the default protocol for urls) if there is no protocol and then validate the url.

Answer (score 0):

You requirement is very specific and cannot be generalized. The `URLValidator` you are using validates correctly. The presence of a **protocol string** (like http://) is **basic requirement** for a URL to be valid. For your needs, you can do following

1. Create a **custom URL validator** (either by extending `URLValidator` or use composition).
2. Inside its validate method, check if the URL has protocol string in the beginning or not. If its not present add it and invoke the `URLValidator` to actually validate the URL.

Comment: Basically decorating URLValidator, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern